# Strange XML map run-time error with Excel VBA

Tags: xml, excel, vba, data-binding

Having some trouble with an XML map in Excel VBA that automatically queries an API and retrieves its data once a value is entered into a specific cell. The map works correctly, refreshing the XML map and retrieving the query data into another desired cell, but despite this success it still forces a Run-time Error within VBA.

The run-time error given is '-2147217376 (80041020)'

'The download of the specified resource has failed.'

Here's my code in VBA. I've changed the example of the website but the format for the query is the same.

```
If Target.Column = 6 And (Target.Row >= 1 And Target.Row <= 10000) Then
Dim CellVariable As String: CellVariable = Target.Value

End If

Dim Map As XmlMap
Set Map = ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps(1)
Map.DataBinding.LoadSettings "http://example.website.com/api/question?name=" & CellVariable & "&api_key=xxxxxxxxx&format=xml"
On Error Resume Next
Map.DataBinding.Refresh
On Error Resume Next
```

Is there a way to override this error somehow? `On Error Resume Next` does not seem to be doing the trick. Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: What line throws the error?  Map.DataBinding.Refresh?

Comment: Sorry, no its the `Map.DataBinding.LoadSettings` line when debugging the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
Map.DataBinding.LoadSettings "http://example.website.com/api/question?name=" & CellVariable & "&api_key=xxxxxxxxx&format=xml"
```

To this (add's brackets):

```
Map.DataBinding.LoadSettings("http://example.website.com/api/question?name=" & CellVariable & "&api_key=xxxxxxxxx&format=xml")
```

Or to this (different method):

```
urlstr = "http://example.website.com/api/question?name=" & CellVariable & "&api_key=xxxxxxxxx&format=xml"
ThisWorkbook.XmlMaps(Map).Import urlStr
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions - the first still generates the same run-time error and the second generates a 'Run-time error 9' (sub script out of range) error though unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I have found that I get this error when Excel is unable to log into the webpage.  The only solution I have found is to browse to the location in **Internet Explorer**, enter my credentials, and tell Internet Explorer to remember my login.
This will work for some time until cookies expire or something and I go and login again.