# Why does the ImportXML Method leads to a runtime error 9?

Tags: excel, vba

The Code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Row = [Namensfilter].Row And Target.Column = [Namensfilter].Column Then
        Dim Displayname As String: Displayname = [Namensfilter].Value + "*"
        Dim Map As XmlMap
        Set Map = ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps(1)
        Dim urlXML As String
        urlXML = "http://direx.corproot.net/DirExWeb/Scripts/Public/GetXML.aspx?displayname=" & Displayname & ""
        ThisWorkbook.XmlMaps(Map).ImportXml urlXML
        Map.DataBinding.Refresh
    End If
End Sub
```

I want to make a XML-Parse in an other table, but when I import the XML-file I get a runtime error 9. When I change the

```
urlXML = "http://direx.corproot.net/DirExWeb/Scripts/Public/GetXML.aspx?displayname=" & Displayname & ""
    ThisWorkbook.XmlMaps(Map).ImportXml urlXML
```

to

```
Map.DataBinding.LoadSettings "http://direx.corproot.net/DirExWeb/Scripts/Public/GetXML.aspx?displayname=" & Displayname & ""
```

or

```
Map.DataBinding.LoadSettings ("http://direx.corproot.net/DirExWeb/Scripts/Public/GetXML.aspx?displayname=" & Displayname & "")
```

I get a really strange error, which I also found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19201881/strange-xml-map-run-time-error-with-excel-vba).
How can I provide the runtime error 9?

Comment: Are you sure the URL is correct?

Comment: Yes, because I importet with that URL the XML file in the second table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to set the * in the link.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Row = [Namensfilter].Row And Target.Column = [Namensfilter].Column Then
        Dim Displayname As String: Displayname = [Namensfilter].Value
        Dim Map As XmlMap
        Set Map = ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps(1)
        Dim urlXML As String
        urlXML = "http://direx.corproot.net/DirExWeb/Scripts/Public/GetXML.aspx?displayname=" & Displayname & "*"
        Map.DataBinding.LoadSettings urlXML
        Map.DataBinding.Refresh
    End If
End Sub
```